# how can I Repeat SVG's without using pattern?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've a `svg` and I'd like to repeat this svg according to width of the device.
I don't want to use `pattern` here.

```html
<svg width="54" height="124" class="absolute left-0 bottom-0 right-0 mx-auto -z-10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"><path d="M1 22h2v-22h18v22h2v2h-22v-2zm7-3v4h3v-4h-3zm5 0v4h3v-4h-3zm-6-5h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-12-4h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-12-4h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-12-4h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2z"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the CSS background repeat facility.

Here is a simple snippet to demonstrate. It repeats the image, having set its width to its 'natural' width (you could of course set its dimensions as you wish) and it repeats in the horizontal direction as many times as needed depending on the width of the container.

```html
<style>
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://ahweb.org.uk/temp.svg);
  background-size: 54px auto;
  background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
</div>
</body>
```

To avoid needing to request a file you could convert the SVG to inline data so it's all contained within the stylesheet.

UPDATE: This snippet does that - using a data conversion online tool. Given the extra requirement to alter color depending on result from an api, you will need your Javascript to set the correct background-image with the fill color obtained from your api.

```html
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg id='svg' fill='red' width='54' height='124' class='absolute left-0 bottom-0 right-0 mx-auto -z-10' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cpath id='path' d='M1 22h2v-22h18v22h2v2h-22v-2zm7-3v4h3v-4h-3zm5 0v4h3v-4h-3zm-6-5h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-12-4h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-12-4h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-12-4h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
</style>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: could you do it without the div? cause I'm using pure svg code here.

Comment: I don't think I absolutely understand. What final result do you want? You could put the background onto the body element for example, but I don't see how you are going to repeat the svg without using some element or other.

Comment: you're right. Reason of using pure svg code is that fill color is coming from the API in my project that's why.

Comment: I've put another snippet in, this time using inline svg which means you can alter the background image string using JS when you get a different color from your api.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of patterns you can use an svg filter [feTile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feTile) like so:

```html
<svg width="240" height="240" class="absolute left-0 bottom-0 right-0 mx-auto -z-10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
        <filter id="image" >
          <feImage xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='54' height='124' class='absolute left-0 bottom-0 right-0 mx-auto -z-10' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath id='kk' d='M1 22h2v-22h18v22h2v2h-22v-2zm7-3v4h3v-4h-3zm5 0v4h3v-4h-3zm-6-5h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-12-4h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-12-4h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-12-4h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm8 0h-2v2h2v-2z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E" width="54" height="124" />
          <feTile/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <rect width="240" height="240" style="filter:url(#image);"/>
</svg>
```

Please observe that I am using a data uri but you can link to the image you need to tile